# django shell_plus timeit call_command?

Tags: django, django-extensions, django-commands

I've written a django command and want to see it's timing so inside `django shell_plus` I do this:

```
import timeit
from django.core.management import call_command

timeit.timeit("""call_command('prova')""", number=3 )
```

The command should run 3 times and output its running time.

If run directly 'call_command' it works, if called inside timeit it throw this error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/timeit.py in timeit(self, number)
    176         gc.disable()
    177         try:
--> 178             timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
    179         finally:
    180             if gcold:

/usr/lib/python3.5/timeit.py in inner(_it, _timer)

NameError: name 'call_command' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timeit` always runs within a new execution context, it doesn't have access to anything you previously imported. You need to pass a separate parameter with setup code:

```
timeit.timeit("call_command('prova')", number=3, setup='from django.core.management import call_command' )
```

See the [timeit docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#examples).